# SSMS error : The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: ssms

Im getting the below error while logging into the database.By default only "Encrpt connection" is checked .

[image: error]

In this case should I need to uncheck "Encrypt connection" and "trust server certificate" Or should I need to check "Encrypt connection" and "trust server certificate" For production.

[image: connection properties]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens when your SSL certificate for the SQL Server machine is not setup properly.

You should be able to workaround it by checking off the "Trust server connection" property for the SSMS connection. (This only affects your specific connection with SSMS.)

Whoever manages the SSL certs should ultimately fix whatever the root issue is, which these Microsoft docs might help with: [The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority error when you connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/error-message-when-you-connect)